# Error during update from 3.4.8 to 3.6.5

Tags: upgrade

When I try to run an update from Joomla 3.4.8 to 3.6.5, I get

> the archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing

and then it just spins.

Googling is not a ton of help. Permissions are set correctly on /tmp.

Upload and post are set to 30M.

I have the full path to /tmp listed in configuration.php.

This is Windows Server 2016, PHP 5.6.38

Any ideas?

Comment: For future miserable souls like I was - I manually uploaded the updated package into /tmp and then ran the update from /index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate. Worked just fine!

Comment: Please help this page to be recognized as "resolved" by "the system" by posting your solution as an answer then award your answer the big green tick (then kindly delete your comment).  Thank you